# Initializiation confusion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Not sure of the appropriate title, but it stems from this discussion:

[Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/syntax-of-new/620402#620402)

On Visual Studio 2008, when I run the following code:

```
struct Stan
{
    float man;
};

int main()
{
    Stan *s1 = new Stan;
    Stan *s2 = new Stan();

}
```

Examining the locals, s1 has an uninitialized float with a random value. s2 is value initialized to 0.

However, if I add a string data member, the float in both instances is uninitialized.

```
struct Stan
    {
            std::string str;
        float man;
    };
```

However, the string in both instances is initialized. I tried adding other non-POD classes instead of a string, but the latter case only occurs if I add a string data member. I gather that adding a string still keeps it a POD class? If it wasn't a POD class, then it should have value initialized regardless of the parenthesis, right? Any ideas why floats(and other primitive data types for that matter) aren't initialized when I add a string data member?

Comment: The 'latter' case is where the primitive data type is not initialized but the string is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a string stops the struct from being a POD class because a POD class must be an aggregate class with no members of type non-POD-struct and `std::string` has (amongst other things) user-declared constructors which makes it a non-POD-struct.

This is a known bug/feature of Visual Studio 2008. It doesn't support C++03 *value initialization* for non-POD types such as the structure in your second example.

With the struct as in your second example what should happen is the float is not initialized by `new Stan` but is zero initialized in `new Stan()`.

Types with a user declared default constructor are initialized by calling that constructor in all cases, this happens correctly.

See [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=100744) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=484295).

Comment: Yea, your second sentence was exactly what I thought should happen also. Glad to know that it's a bug/feature.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you observe is a conforming behavior from the point of view of C++98 specification of the language.

The type in your first example is a so-called POD (Plain Old Data) type. When you apply the `()` initializer to a POD class type it performs zero-initialization of all data members of the class.

The type in your second example is not a POD type (because of the non-POD member `str`). When you apply the `()` initializer to a non-POD class type, it simply calls the class constructor to perform initialization. In your case the implicit [compiler-provided] constructor will properly initialize the `str` member, but will not do anything for the `man` member, which is why you see garbage in it.

Again, this is the correct behavior in C++98. It was changed in C++03. In C++03 the `()` initializer will perform *value-initialization*. In accordance with the rules of value-initialization, in your second example, the `man` field should also get zero-initialized in response to `()` initializer.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976185/what-is-the-difference-between-new-myclass-vs-new-myclass for more detailed explanation .